# Why does my methods get called for unknown reason?

Tags: vue.js

I have functions `filterData` that update a chart data based on several inputs. However, when an irrelevant input gets changed (like typing in a text-field), the functions get called every time, resulting the chart getting re-rendered. I have logged the output and none of the parameters changed.

Why does the function get called? Is there anyway to track it or am I doing it wrong.

```
<DeviceChart :input-data="filterData(inputData, filters, otherParams)"/>
```

```
export default {
  methods: {
    filterData(inputData, inputFilters, otherParameters) {
      console.log('Filter data has been called...')
      ...
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: General answer, when I'm asking myself "Why this method is called", then I use chrome dev tools debugger to understand why the method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a little bit of background.

A Vue template will be compiled down to a `render` function. When a component renders this function is called and it returns a tree of VDOM nodes. These VDOM nodes describe the child components and the corresponding DOM. When a component subsequently updates this `render` function is called again, returning a new VDOM tree. Vue then compares the old and new trees and decides what changes to make.

You can think of the `render` function as being very similar to a computed property. The return type, a tree of VDOM nodes, might be a bit alien to you but apart from that it's just like any computed property you might write yourself. It runs, tracks dependencies and returns a value. If those dependencies subsequently change it will be run again.

Importantly, just like with a computed property, Vue does not have detailed knowledge of precisely how you use your dependencies within that function. Any change to a dependency will cause the whole `render` function to be re-run.

This may sound expensive but usually it's not a significant overhead. Comparing the trees of VDOM nodes is also usually quite a cheap operation. The expensive part is updating the DOM and you'd have to do that whatever approach you use.

So when you talk about an 'irrelevant input' changing you need to keep in mind that the template (i.e. `render` function) will always be run as a whole. If any dependency changes then all the code in your template will re-run.

In your case you have a method call to filter the value for `input-data`. That will be called every time the template runs. The input and chart may be separate components within the template but that doesn't matter, the whole template needs to run to generate the new VDOM tree. The data behind your input is a dependency of the template and when it changes (as a result of typing into the input) the template re-runs.

However, child components won't necessarily be re-rendered. When Vue is comparing the VDOM trees for the parent component's nodes it attempts to pair up children from the old and new trees (that's what the `key` is for, to provide a hint about which children to pair up). Once it has paired up the children it will update the props for any children that need it. If the props of a child haven't changed then that child won't need to re-render itself.

In your case I'm assuming that `input-data` is an array. Each time the method `filterData` is called it'll return a new array. The array might be 'the same' as far as you're concerned but it isn't actually the same array. From a JavaScript `===` perspective the value has changed. I don't know precisely what `DeviceChart` does with that data but that is most likely what is causing it to re-render. For Vue components re-rendering is a cheap process and not usually worth worrying about but chances are your chart is using some third-party libraries and re-rendering may not be so trivial.

The easiest solution is probably just to use a computed property for the `input-data`. As computed properties are cached you'll get the same array every time the template runs. The cache is only invalidated if the dependencies of the computed function change, so other dependencies of the template won't have any effect.

There are numerous alternatives, most of them painful. Generally these involve storing the filtered value in `data` and trying to update it just when required. I would not recommend trying anything like that if you can help it.

Computed properties get fiddly if you have a loop.

A viable alternative that also works well with a loop is to introduce a wrapper component for your chart. If you pass `inputData`, `filters` and `otherParams` to that wrapper component as 3 separate props then responsibility for performing the actual filtering can be moved into the wrapper component. So long as those 3 props don't change the wrapper won't be re-rendered when the outer template re-renders. I would still advise using a computed property within the wrapper but it wouldn't matter so much as the template won't be run anyway.